# Is it appropriate to use a method within same object context ($this) that normally returns JSON response for client?

Tags: php, laravel

This May sound like a silly question but, I have a method that normally returns a JSON response to the client side. But now I need the same method within the class to prevent DRY. Something like:

```
public function deleteChild($id){
    // delete the element with given id ...

    if($success){
        return response()->json(['success'=>'successfully deleted'], 200); 
    }else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'could not be deleted'], 422); 
    }
}
```

This method is already used by the client side. But now I have another one that needs this method as well. Something like:

```
public function deleteMaster($id){
    $master = Master::find($id);

    foreach($child as $master->children){
        $child_json_response = $this->deleteChild($child->id);

        $response_data = $child_json_response->getData();

        if($response_data->error){
            // handle child error response
            // ...
        }
        // delete master itself 
    }
}
```

Here I can extract the response data with `getData()` and process it.

Is this the right way to use a sibling function that returns a JSON response (actually made for client-side) or should I create another method that returns direct results serving server-side only?

Comment: IMHO you should extract the code which generates the data and call this from your `deleteChild()` and `deleteMaster()` methods.

Comment: What is the context of your methods? Controller?

Comment: @NigelRen do you mean to extract the **// delete element with given id ...** part as a new method (perhaps) as deleteChildElement() and call this part from both deleteMaster() and deleteChild() explicitly. So the methods deleteMaster() and deleteChild() would do the same process but different responses?

Comment: @Shizzen83 yes it is within a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [Response macro](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#response-macros)

Into a service provider's `boot`, add this:

```
\Illuminate\Http\Response::macro('deleteJson', function ($success) {
    return $success
        ? $this->json(['success'=>'successfully deleted'], 200)
        : $this->json(['error'=>'could not be deleted'], 422);
}
```

```
public function deleteChild($id){
    // delete element with given id ...

    return response()->deleteJson($success);
}
```

Comment: @Shinzzen83 I think that would be a little exaggerated for such a simple process. Wouldn't it?

Comment: You should think about your project becoming bigger and bigger. You would probably use the same thing dozens of times, using a macro is then very useful. Moreover if some day, you want to update the render, by the way, you must update only 1 thing instead of dozens.